# MarkLogic field index weighting rules for included child with excluded parent

Tags: indexing, marklogic, marklogic-8

From [MarkLogic's documentation on fields](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/fields#id_38755):

> If a field has two or more elements with different weights and, if one of those elements is a child of another element, then the weight of the parent element is used and the weight of the child element is ignored.

But it's not clear what happens when an ancestor and descendant have weights and the direct parent of the descendant is excluded. For example, say I have a document:

```
<X>
  <A>
    <B>
      <C>
```

`<X>`(root) is excluded from the field, `<A>` is included with `weight=1`, `<B>` is excluded, and `<C>` is included with `weight=2`. Will a field match for a term in `<C>` be weighted with 1 or with 2? (And is there any way to check how indexed weights are contributing to scores to confirm that a configuration like this is working as intended?)

Answer (score 1):

I ran a quick test, and that seems to contradict the documentation. I created a field called `test`. It excludes root, and element `B`, but includes `A` with weight `1.0`, and `B` with weight '2.0'. I then ran the following in QConsole:

```
xdmp:document-insert("/field-test-X.xml", <X>test</X>, (), "field-test"),
xdmp:document-insert("/field-test-XA.xml", <X><A>test</A></X>, (), "field-test"),
xdmp:document-insert("/field-test-XAB.xml", <X><A><B>test</B></A></X>, (), "field-test"),
xdmp:document-insert("/field-test-XABC.xml", <X><A><B><C>test</C></B></A></X>, (), "field-test"),
xdmp:document-insert("/field-test-XAC.xml", <X><A><C>test</C></A></X>, (), "field-test"),
xdmp:document-insert("/field-test-XC.xml", <X><C>test</C></X>, (), "field-test")
;

cts:search(collection("field-test"), cts:field-word-query("test", "test")) ! (xdmp:node-uri(.) || " - " || cts:score(.))
```

It returned me:

```
/field-test-XABC.xml - 30976
/field-test-XC.xml - 30976
/field-test-XAC.xml - 30976
/field-test-XA.xml - 22528
```

That tells us that the word `test` inside element `C` gets a higher score, regardless if it occurs within `A` directly, or with an excluded element `B` in between, or even on its own. In all cases the result gets highest score, which indicates that the higher boost was applied.

HTH!

Comment: Wait.. the docs seem correct for `cts:field-value-query`, but not for `cts:field-word-query`. The behavior seems inconsistent. I'll file a bug report anyhow..

Comment: Very interesting...so when a term match occurs in a descendant element, using `cts:field-value-query` it is scored based on the ancestor weight, or for `cts:field-word-query` it gets the score of the descendant?